# Unity get the trigger that has caused a OnCollision... event

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to make a player controller that jumps only when a specified in a property `Collider` collides with anything. For now, I can detect when a collision has occurred, but can't detect which are the two bodies that have collided. Does the event trigger only when one of the colliding bodies is the one that the script is applied to. If so, how can I handle events on behalf of other objects (or even better, detect global collisions)

Here is my player controller hierarchy:

```
Capsule
|
+- Camera
|
+- Floor Collider
```

P. s.: Sorry for the question's short length

Comment: Can you post a bit more as to what you are trying to achieve? To me it just sounds like you want to check which object is colliding with your player, then to allow your player to jump. Instead of checking collision, I would recommend using a [`Raycast`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.Raycast.html) and only casting to layers you define as the ground.

Comment: Please show your code .. basically all message methods related to collision/trigger detection always have a parameter telling you exactly with what you collided.... So you can filter using an exact reference, tags, layers, a certain component type, names, .....

Comment: What I want is to check what object caused the collision, I don't see how my code would help to solve this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me see if i got your question, you want to detect when the player is touching the floor so that it can only jump when on the floor. Is this right?

The floor has a `Collider` as well right? Add a `tag` on the floor object so that we can identify who is the `Collider`.

And then on the Player Controller do something like:

```
void OnCollisionEnter(Collision other)
{
    if(other.gameObject.tag == "floor") 
    {
        allowJump = true;
    }
}
```

And the opposite so that we know that the player can't jump

```
void OnCollisionExit(Collision other)
{
    if(other.gameObject.tag == "floor") 
    {
        allowJump = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: I want this to happen only when a collision caused by `Floor Collider` happens

Comment: Then add a script with Collision code on the component that has the floor collider